# Create temporary file on specific partition

Tags: java, filesystems, cross-platform, nio

I want to write contents to a file atomically. However I have to deal with a variety of filesystems, that don't support atomic writes or locks.

So I want to write my changes to a temporary file first and then move this file to the target location, overwriting the existing (old) file.

For this move operation to be as fast as possible, I want my temporary file to be on the same partition as the target file. But I don't want it to be in the target directory, as this might interfere with some 3rd party applications.

Is there a (cross-platform) way to create a temporary file (using NIO) on a specific partition? Or is the only way to ensure the move operation being fast to make the temporary file a sibling of the target file?

Comment: if it's a temp file... why you need to write in same partition? java allows you to create cross platform temporal files without problems....

Comment: @JordiCastilla for the move operation to work. a move across different partitions is a copy followed by a delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
     // creates temporary file
     f = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".txt", new File("C:/"));
     // deletes file when the virtual machine terminate
     f.deleteOnExit();
```

(1) you can specify the folder (partition) as parameter 3 in createTempFile

(2) usually you should put your temp files in a temp folder, which you need to determine.

(3) you can gain the drive (partition) from your original file.

Comment: This might work for windows, but the problem is, that mount points of partitions don't necessarily need to be the root folder.

Comment: mount points usually contain /mnt/ don't they? or did you try using FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()

Comment: nope, mount points can be just _any_ directory. Might also vary greatly from OS to OS. `FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()` might be of interest, will take a look